# Look Around and re.sub()

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to know how re.sub() works.
The following example is in a book I am reading.

I want "1234567890" to be "1,234,567,890".

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))")
pattern.sub(r"\g<0>,", "1234567890")
"1,234,567,890"
```

Then, I changed "\g<0>" to "\g<1>" and it did not work.
The result was "890,890,890,890".
Why?
I want to know exactly how the capturing and replacing of re.sub()and look ahead mechanism  is working.

Comment: you actually captured the last three digits. It will replace every match with the  chars present inside the group index 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `890` repeated because it is Group 1 (= `\g<1>`), and you replace every 3 digits with the last captured Group 1 (which is `890`).

One more thing here is `(\d{3})+` that also captures groups of 3 digits one by one until the end (because of the `(?!\d)` condition), and places *only the last captured group of characters* into Group 1. And you are using it to replace each 3-digit chunks in the input string.

See visualization at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uG7xL6/8).

Comment: Why only the last captured group is applied to all of the what to be replaced ?

Comment: @q2ven `(\d)+` will match one or more digits but captures only the last digit. Same happens here.

Comment: @q2ven: I have shortened the explanation to only stress the most important details.

Comment: I've understood it, but why \g<0> can be each three digits ?

Comment: `\g<0>` is the whole match. `\g<1>` is only the first captured group. Replacement is performed from left to right: 1) `\g<0>` takes the 1st 1 up to 3 digits (it is "1" because after it we have 3-digit groups until the end) and replaces the text with itself ("1") and adding a comma, then 2) grabs the next 3 digits (because `{1,3}` is greedy), and `\g<0>` now is equal to "234" and again this text is replaced with itself, and so on. When you use `\g<1>`, you replace each of these with the last 3 digits captured.